# Tutorial for placing UITableView in TableViewCell's Content View?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have been trying to find a tutorial to do the following:

I have a `UITableViewController` with two sections with 1 row per section.

The row in the second section shows a list of items which are just a list of strings (like a basic `UITableView` with the Basic cell type).

So basically, if I have 2 items to list in the `UITableViewCell`, I would like to create a `UITableView` in its `contentView` with 1 section and 2 rows, each row having a `UILabel` for me to access.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you put a UITableView inside of a UITableView?

Comment: I have a Core Data Entity that links to other entities. I want to display which entities it's linked to as a list in one cell.

Comment: So just populate the first tableView with that data

Comment: The first table view has other information. If you aren't going to help, then don't post...   This table view is not scrollable. Think of it as a paragraph with one word per line, k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, I think you should abandon your idea with table view inside table view. The outer table view will scroll, and the inner one also, resulting in a very confusing and potentially frustrating user experience. The standard setup for what you describe (master detail) is to present the detail in a separate table view that animates in and out; or to divide your table view into sections with the data (using the sections below for the additional data you mention).

If you want to proceed with your idea, you should be able to explain, why the user has to see the second section while scrolling the first section. I think it will be very hard to argue.

That being said, it is of course possible to include a table view in a table view cell. Simply drag the table view into the cell in interface builder, give it a unique name, wire it up with your controller (delegate and datasource) and make sure you distinguish between the outer and inner table views in your delegate and datasource methods.

For example,

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

   if (tableView==innerTableView) {
      // get and configure the cells
   }
   else {
      // configure the cells of the original table view
   }
}
```

Comment: I abandoned my original idea. Just gotta keep it simple. Thanks